# How can I filter XHR requests by name in Chrome developer tools / Firebug

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

My problem is the webapp I am working on is pinging the server at short interval so I have many lines coming in Network tab of Chrome developer tools.

- First problem: Chrome start to be irresponsive and then crash
- Second problem: I want to remove all the ping request and have only the
  request I want to monitor.

Is there a way to filter XHR request by name or pattern ?

*Bonus : same question apply for Firebug*

In this screenshot I wish to filter our all 'bind' requests.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Feature request logged on http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117702

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature was added in September 2012: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117702#c4

Cmd/Ctr-F to filter in developer tools Network tab.

Comment: Do you know if there is away to do a NOT filter? For example I want to exclude .map files but see the rest of the XHR requests.

Answer (score 5):

Make use of negative text filters recently announced [here](https://twitter.com/addyosmani/status/549588196837695488) (they should make it to the stable release in the near future if not already).

Chrome developer docs don't yet appear well updated but what is documented is available at

[Chrome developer docs - Sorting and filtering](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#sorting-and-filtering)

Answer (score 0):

Firebug's Net panel currently only allows to sort the requests, it doesn't allow filtering besides by type (*HTML*, *CSS*, *JS*, *XHR*, *Images*, *Flash* and *Media*).
Though there are two requests covering this:

- [Issue 3560](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=3560): Search in Net panel to act as a filter
- [Issue 4829](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4829): Custom Filters for Net Panel (other panels?)