# Filter files shown in Network tab within Google Development Tools

Tags: javascript, file, debugging, google-chrome, filter

In Google Chrome > right click HTML page > Inspect Element > Network tab

Is there a way to filter the files you see in his tab when requests are made from the browser?  I sometimes get flooded with certain files during development, when I'm trying to debug, and I really only care about looking at one particular file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I filter XHR requests by name in Chrome developer tools / Firebug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644098/how-can-i-filter-xhr-requests-by-name-in-chrome-developer-tools-firebug)

Comment: Note - the accepted answer there should work (CTRL-F, then check "Filter").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer copied from another Question:

This feature was added in September 2012: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117702#c4

Cmd/Ctr-F to filter in developer tools Network tab.